# Windows 10 thinks it's a USB install

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, usb, windows-registry, windows-update

At my work I used my hard drive with a sata to usb device to see if a computer would even boot, it did

but now because of that Windows 10 believes it's a usb install and I've been having more hangs and other things.

now Windows sees an update, but won't take it because it's on a usb, even though it's only been booted on that computer once, and has always been in my computer other-wise.

Please if anyone knows how to make it think it's a normal HDD install again, please tell me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was also an issue in Windows 8(.1). [There you can fix it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2778881/multiple-operations-fail-if-windows-8-is-improperly-identified-as-a-windows-to-go-installation) by opening a cmd.exe as admin, run this command

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control /v PortableOperatingSystem /t REG_DWORD /d 0
```

an reboot.

Windows uses this PortableOperatingSystem key to detect if you use a regular or WindowsToGo version.

Comment: I just deleted the key using regedit about 4 hours after I made the Question, thankyou ,please add the regedit way too. marking as answer anyway as it works